# Picklist value not retrieve through force IDE

Tags: metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

I am trying to deployed opportunity record type and business process but it is showing the error :

```
 File Name:    objects/Opportunity.object
   Full Name:  Opportunity.Third Party Fee Page
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Picklist value: Closed - Unresponsive not found

   File Name:    objects/Opportunity.object
   Full Name:  Opportunity.Third Party Negotiation
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Picklist value: Closed-Duplicate not found

   File Name:    objects/Opportunity.object
   Full Name:  Opportunity.Allied_Comp_Loss
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Picklist value: Best Case in picklist: ForecastCategoryName not found
```

Can you please tell me how can retrieve picklist value from the source org or removed the error

Comment: Can you share your package.xml file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Opportunity.Allied_Comp_Loss</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Opportunity.Allied Comp Loss</members>
        <name>BusinessProcess</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>

Comment: Add your packge.xml code by **[edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/244310/edit)**. Also please update it to latest version in file and try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy changes to fields upon which your Opportunity Sales Process and Record Type are dependent alongside those metadata entities.  `Opportunity.StageName` is a dependency for your customized Sales Process.

Upon review I'm actually not sure how to deploy changes to `ForecastCategoryName`. It may be part of [`ForecastingSettings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_forecastingsettings.htm).

As cropredy points out, handling `Opportunity.StageName` is treated via the `StandardValueSet` Metadata API entity, because these *aren't* custom fields as the first version of my answer erroneously treated them. The [value set name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) for `Opportunity.StageName` is `OpportunityStage`.

Comment: not `StandardValueSet` ?

Comment: @cropredy Sigh. I should turn my brain on first. Thanks. You also made me realize there's no StandardValueSet for forecast category names. I don't use forecasting and I'm not sure where that lives or if it varies between collaborative/customizable forecasting - do you know?

Comment: regrettably, no - forecast category was something I haven't dealt with in a long time and I'm sure I probably manually made changes in PROD :-) . - there is this metadataAPI type for collab https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_forecastingsettings.htm and global picklist for otherwise: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalpicklistvalue.htm worth investigating

Answer (score 0):

I've had the issue deploying changes to ForecastCategoryName values, and this answer comes up high on google. Here are my findings.

The most promising results I got was by making a small change to one of the  picklist values and retrieving whatever changed using `sf project retrieve preview`. This is what I got:

```
Will Retrieve [1] files.
 Type             Fullname             Path 
 ──────────────── ──────────────────── ──── 
 StandardValueSet ForecastCategoryName
```

Looks like it would be a standard value set, which makes sense. When I tried to actually retrieve, nothing happened. I'm finding the lack of a path in in the above result indicative. I suppose this picklist is just not supported in metadata right now (version 59.0).